# Asynchronous data filled in dropdown based on a text field : only HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Can anybody help me with this thing.

I need just 2 fields. One Text Field and one DropDown field.

Now, we have a values like the following :-
[ 1 -> A, B, C ] . [ 2 -> X, Y, Z ] . [ 3 -> P, Q, R ]

Now, what exactly I need is a plain HTML/Javascript (or JSP) in which
if I enter 1 in the text field, the drop down should automatically be filled with values A, B and C. 
If I edit the TextField and input 2 now, the Drop Down should dynamically change to X, Y and Z.

The change should be asynchronous, I can't use any button and the change should be immediate with each TextField input.

Is it possible to do using simple JavaScript and HTML ?  Please help.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. We help each other to resolve specific problems that arise while you are trying some solution. What have you tried?

Comment: I was thinking may be we can run some javascript function on onkeyup event but I have no clue how can i dynamically fill a dropdown. Is that anywhere near the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I did it myself. Ofcourse google helped.. :D
I'm putting it here in case anybody ever needs it.

I've called a javascript method on onkeyup event of the TextField.
Inside that function, I'm calling two other methods, one for adding up values to the dropdown, one for deleting all the dropdown values whenever they are required after checking the value of the TextField.

Following are the methods for adding and deleting values :-

```
function clearDropdownValues(selection)
{
var i;
for(i=selection.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    selection.remove(i);
}
}


function addOptionToDropdown(selection, value, text )
{
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = text;
optn.value = value;
selection.options.add(optn);
}
```